# How can I transform a dplyr::data_frame into an html table for shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a custom template in shiny, and I want it to show a dataframe using the aesthetics of the template. For this reason, I need to parse this data frame:

```
data_frame(name=letters[1:5], value=1:5) 
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

   name value
  (chr) (int)
1     a     1
2     b     2
3     c     3
4     d     4
5     e     5
```

Into this

```
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                      </tr>
```

And then put it in the `index.html` file using `{{tableName}}`. Which would be the most appropriate way?

ps:I am totally open to consider a different approach you think that mine does not make fully sense.

Comment: `knitr::kable(df, 'html)` make nice simple HTML tables, or see `DT` for interactive ones.

Answer (score 2):

The `print.xtable` function has a 'type' argument that lets you construct html-tables

```
require(xtable)
require(dplyr)
obj <- data_frame(name=letters[1:5], value=1:5)
print( xtable(obj), type="html")
<!-- html table generated in R 3.2.3 by xtable 1.8-2 package -->
<!-- Sat Mar 19 16:57:05 2016 -->
<table border=1>
<tr> <th>  </th> <th> name </th> <th> value </th>  </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 1 </td> <td> a </td> <td align="right">   1 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 2 </td> <td> b </td> <td align="right">   2 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 3 </td> <td> c </td> <td align="right">   3 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 4 </td> <td> d </td> <td align="right">   4 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 5 </td> <td> e </td> <td align="right">   5 </td> </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however this does not reflect the exact format of the table in my template. For example, I still need to add the tag `<th>` and the attribute `scope="row"`

Comment: Some people just cannot be satisfied.

Comment: If I simply wanted to transform a table in html, I wouldn't have posted a sample of how I want the html code to look like.
Some people just cannot understand the difference between a solution, and  "a kind of a way of doing the same thing, except that is wrong".

Comment: You asked for "... [parse] into something like this." You should edit your question rahter than making ungrateful comments if it needs to be "exactly like this" which is not at all suggested by your original and still unedited question.

Comment: I am not sure editing the question will help, since apparently my first and quite clear comment didn't help either. By the way, the interpretation of "something like this" is just a matter of the level of precision one is used to.

Comment: I would say that "something like" is inherently imprecise. In SO you are asked  NOT  to use comments to clarify the question. You are _requested_ to use the editing features. Please read the Help section more thoroughly than you appear to have done so far.

Comment: I specified that I meant to use a custom template, thus a function that outputs a script and doesn't allow to add attributes to the code is quite sloppy. Regardless of the connotation you would give to "something like".